# Access-Main Report with 4 Subreports running VERY slowly

Tags: forms, ms-access, report

Good Afternoon,

I have a personnel report based on employee ID with four subreports to reflect various activities of the personnel. The user selects the person's name from a form and then selects the FY for which they want their activity. They then press a macro button to get the report to run and that takes upwards of a minute to run. Can any one give some insight as to why it may be this slow?

Comment: We need a lot more information. A few general things to check: table relationships, column indexing, any domain functions like `DLookup`, network shares, defunct printers/drivers, etc. We really can't help unless we can see what you are trying to run.

Comment: I once had to filter a database of about 30'000 Persons by several different attributes (some boolean, some timestamp and worst: strings ("LIKE")). It took several minutes depending on the attributes chosen. I switched to having a "SELECTED" boolean in the table and going through the attributes one by one - wizard-style. And with every attribute I deselected the ones that didn't apply. Every songle step worked faster than the user could click through the wizard ;)